# how to calculate the difference between the sum of each column from different datagridview and to show it in a datagridview

Tags: sql, vb.net

Hello I am a student in computer science , we ve got a inventory system project to do.
I have a problem
using sql I know how to importe sql to  datagridview. I know have to save data in sql database using vb
but  I still don t know how to calculate the difference of sum of each column from each different datagridview and to show it in datagridview.
My gol is:
I have a datagridview1 that shows the quantity of purchsases of a product in column A.and I have another datagridview2 that shows the quantity of sells of the same product in column B.
Datagridview1 is on form1.vb.
datagridview is on form2.vb0
what I want is : to calculate and view the stock the stock still available on new form3.vb on datagridview3.
thanks in advance

Comment: Use a single Form and a single DataGridView  that shows the total of purchases and sells in adjacent Cells (so it's easier to read) and a third Column that performs the operations automatically, using a calculated Column (a feature you should read about). If you don't want to use a calculated Column, you can use the `CellFormatting` event of your DataGridView to perform the same operation on a Column you can add to the Control add (or the Designer, why not).

Comment: it's not easy as you think because imagine you have several products the data gridview should view how much sells and puchases for each product and also its stock which still available, do you have any idea how to do it ?

Comment: Purchases and sells per product are generated by a SQL query. The calculated Column can also come from the query. Or, as described, with a Calculated Column or using the DataGridView features. Do you know how to `Sum()` Columns values using a query? In case you don't, take a look at it and post the code you tried (in case it fails, that is).

Comment: Yes I know how to do it on sql , I have for example table1 called essay with a column called Val1 and a second table called essay2 with a column Val1  and did the query  to calculate stock : select (select  SUM(essay.Val1) from essay)-(select  SUM(essay2.Val1) from essay2);  and it worked but I I dont know how to view the  stock for each procut , could you help me please?

Comment: You are required to post the code you have tried, a real descriptions of the objects you're working with, the definition of the data Tables you're interested in and all other details you think are required to reproduce the problem you have with your code. I.e., post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the following steps (For selected Row):

- Dim Data1 As String = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(Column Number).Text
- Dim Data2 As String = GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells(Column Number).Text
- Data1 - Data2
- Save the result in a new table (database)
- Show the new gridview3
- Repeat for all rows.